# Keep all forms statuses in one component with different tabs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with 2 tabs and 2 forms, in each tab one form :

`tab1.component.ts` :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.params = getParams();
}
getParams() {
    return {
        text : 'test'
        form: {
            status: this.form.invalid
        }
    };
}
```

`tab1.component.html` :

```
<validate [params]="this.params">
</validate>
```

`tab2.component.ts` :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.params = getParams();
}
getParams() {
    return {
        text : 'test 1'
        form: {
            status: this.form.invalid
        }
    };
}
```

`tab2.component.html` :

```
<validate [params]="this.params">
</validate>
```

The component `validate` :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'validate',
    templateUrl: './validate.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./validate.component.scss']
})
export class Validate implements OnInit {

@Input() params?: TabContentParam;

public showButton = false;
...
}
```

`validate.component.html` :

```
<button *ngIf="showButton" mat-flat-button>Button</button>
```

And I have a common component `<validate></validate>`. So the idea is to put `showButton` in true when both params `form.status` is true. Like I did I check only the last status, and is wrong. The question is how I can check both statuses ? I check and when I load the page, is rendering both tabs with both forms. Thx in advance.

Comment: I have added the answer, please check.. Please not I wrote the code just in the answer section. If you can share a demo stackbiltz link with the code, it will be easier to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create shared service for it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TabButtonService {

constructor() { }

    showButton : {
      tab1:false,
      tab2: false,
    }
}
```

tab2.component.ts

```
constructor(tabButtonService :TabButtonService ) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.params = getParams();
   this.tabButtonService.showButton.tab1 = true
}
```

Repeat for tab1.component.ts

validateComponent:

```
export class Validate implements OnInit {

   constructor(tabButtonService :TabButtonService ) { }

  @Input() params?: TabContentParam;

  public showButton = this.tabButtonService.showButton.tab1 && this.tabButtonService.showButton.tab2;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not working, I get the message `TabButtonService.showButton is undefined` :(